# How should I include PlotLegends in the given code to get the given plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I include `PlotLegends` in this code

```
{data1, data2} = Transpose[Table[{2, 8/n}, {n, 20}]];

a = ListLogPlot[data1, Frame -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 10, Red]];
b = ListLogPlot[data2, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, Mesh -> All];

Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None]
```

to give me a plot such the legends are like this picture

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all in a single `ListLogPlot`:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, 
 Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"◆", 10}, {"●", 10}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
 Mesh -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}]
```

[image]

Altenatively, add the option `PlotLegends` in each plot. Show combines the legends automatically:

```
a = ListLogPlot[data1, Frame -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Style["◆", 10, Red], 
   PlotLegends -> {"first"}];

b = ListLogPlot[data2, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, Mesh -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"second"}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]];

Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Update:** To get a picture like the second picture in OP we can use `PlotStyle`. If we specify different colors for points and lines in `b` using, say,

```
   PlotStyle ->  Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5], Black, 
     LineColor -> Blue]
```

the lines and markers in the legend are automatically colored  to match the specification in `PlotStyle`.

So, we can use the first approach as follows:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> {False, True}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"◆", 16}, {"●", 14}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5], Black, 
    LineColor -> Blue]},
 Mesh -> All, PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}]
```

[image]

And  modify the second approach as follows:

```
a = ListLogPlot[data1, Frame -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Style["◆", 14, Red], 
   PlotLegends -> {"first"}];

b = ListLogPlot[data2, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle ->  Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5], Black, 
     LineColor -> Blue], 
   Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[9], 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"second"}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}]];

Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another problem. How can I get a result like the second picture in the question? and how can I control the legend and the legendmarkers size?

Comment: @charmin, please see the update.

Comment: Once more, I appreciate your time and answer.